# What does "unanimously disagreed" mean?

Tags: oxymoron

The complete sentence runs as follows:

> The judges *unanimously disagreed* that he was fit to compete.

What does it mean?

Comment: It does seem a bit self-contradictory at first, but the "disagreed" here does not mean that the judges disagreed with each other but that they disagreed with the presumption that he was fit to compete.

Comment: @HotLicks Is probably right but I'd love it if the sentence meant "they all agreed to disagree among each other", like an ackowledged state of chaos :-)

Comment: I guess the writer is trying to convey that the verdict from the judges was unanimous decision rather than a majority decision. I agree it's a little clumsy.

Comment: This could also be an example of writing to form.  I have seen this often in process-based decisions like legal documents and government decision-making, e.g. The judgement is <decision> that <defendant> is <proposal>.  They do this for clarity across documents and then journalists copy that to ensure the facts are described accurately.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Someone was asserting that he was fit to compete. The judges *all* disagreed with that statement. In other words, the judges *all* disagreed with the statement that he was fit to compete; in other words, the judges *all* disagreed that he was fit to compete; in other words, the judges *unanimously* disagreed that he was fit to compete.

Not exactly a specimen of good writing, I have to say…

[Edit: Dan points out, and I agree, that this could also be 'a deliberate play of on words from the standard *unanimously agreed* used for effect'.]

Comment: Since "unanimously disagreed that he was fit" is in the questions, shouldn't you say: i.e., unanimously *agreed* that he was *un*fit"?

Comment: @MartinF Agreeing with something and disagreeing with the opposite aren't necessarily the same thing, I wouldn't call myself fit but I also wouldn't call myself unfit

Comment: "Not exactly a specimen of good writing" - It sounds slightly contrived to me, though also sounds like a deliberate play on words from the standard "unanimously agreed" used for effect.

Comment: @NickA That may be true when using the word "fit" in a general context as in "good physical shape" (I also think of myself as neither particularily fit nor particularily unfit). But when used in "fit to compete", then you're either fit or you're unfit.

Comment: @Arthur Sure, but my point of *"Agreeing with something and disagreeing with the opposite aren't necessarily the same thing"* still stands

Comment: @NickA and that comment wasn't *in general* it was *in context*. Do you think this specific instance is wrong? And if not, I'm not sure what that comment was about, as the statement "Turtles aren't on Mars" is an equally valid thing to say and is about as related.

Comment: @vlaz Add "to compete in a general knowledge quiz" (or similar) to the end of each statement that I provided in my comment (fitting with the context of the question) and it still makes sense and is of course related. Your comment however is not remotely related.

Comment: @Dan OK, fair enough, that is a possibility.

Comment: They didn't disagree with each other, they unanimously agreed.  On what did they agree?  That he was not fit.  This is logically equivalent to agreeing that he's unfit.  The connotation is perhaps softer in terms of sparing the feelings of the person being judged, but the judgment is exactly the same in the specifically limited context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what it means:

> All of the judges decided that he was unfit to compete.

Comment: Same as @linguistictum's answer?

Comment: The same in effect, but linguisticturn did not take that last step.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is recognising that "*disagreed*" isn't standing on its own.  It's actually paired with the following phrase - "*disagreed that (assertion)*", and loses its meaning if separated.

You can say that "*the panel unanimously agreed*" without saying what they agreed on; you can't say that some people *unanimously disagreed* without knowing the idea (at least implied) with which they disagreed.

We could expand the original sentence to make it clearer: "*The judges were unanimous: each one disagreed that he was fit to compete.*"

A version where the claim is implicit: "*He said he was fit to compete.  The judges unanimously disagreed.*"